# There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'V' to 'System.IEquatable<V>'

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following extension methods, which compile successfully and behave as designed.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct {
    return source.Where(item => !item.Equals(default(T)));
}

public static IEnumerable<V> SelectNotEmpty<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, V> selector) where V : struct {
    return source.Select(selector).WhereNotEmpty();
}
```

However, in an effort to avoid the boxing, I added a new generic constraint as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct, IEquatable<T> {
    return source.Where(item => !item.Equals(default(T)));
}

public static IEnumerable<V> SelectNotEmpty<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, V> selector) where V : struct, IEquatable<T> {
    return source.Select(selector).WhereNotEmpty(); // compile error!
}
```

I'm now getting a compile error where `SelectNotEmpty` calls `WhereNotEmpty`:

> The type 'V' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   or method
>   'MyExtensions.WhereNotEmpty(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'.
>   There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'V' to
>   'System.IEquatable'.

I'm sure I've made a silly mistake, but I can't see it. Could anyone point it out for me please?

Comment: Explain to me why v is equatable to t in the second method.

Comment: did you mean the constraint for  `SelectNotEmpty` to be `where V : struct, IEquatable<V>` ?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. It was a simple typo, which I would have spotted if I had used more readable names for the type parameters. :-(

Comment: It's very nice the Christian solved his problem. But does noone else think that this question is too localized? Do we want people searching for *anything* to find this in the future? Thanks.

Comment: @Jon: Fair point. Close it if you want, I'm just happy to have an answer. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your constraint on V should be

```
where V : struct, IEquatable<V>
```

The type `T` in WhereNotEmpty should be `IEquatable<T>` and you are passing an `IEnumerable<V>` into `WhereNotEmpty` from `SelectNotEmpty` after you apply the transformation.

```
public static IEnumerable<V> SelectNotEmpty<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, V> selector) where V : struct, IEquatable<V>
{
    return source.Select(selector).WhereNotEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Aaargh, I feel so dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
public static IEnumerable<V> SelectNotEmpty<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, V> selector) where V : struct, IEquatable<T> {
    return source.Select(selector).WhereNotEmpty(); 
}
```

on

```
    public static IEnumerable<V> SelectNotEmpty<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, V> selector) where V : struct, IEquatable<V> {
    return source.Select(selector).WhereNotEmpty(); 
}
```